# T-SQL - Set variable during SELECT statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, string, t-sql, count

I'd like to set a variable in the middle of an SQL query.

I have multiple 'flags' and I'd like the query to report all the flags about a customer that are true, in the Result column.
Because of this, I can't use a CASE statement since it stops evaluating once it finds its first 'True' statement.
To get around this, I'm using a set if IF statements to append the relevant flag to a variable and then report that variable in the Result column. However, I'm not getting anywhere with it.

The code below, of course, does not run. How can I reorganize this query so that it's kosher?

The desired result is this:
[image]

Here's the code:

```
DECLARE 
@CountOfOrders int = 0,
@resultstring varchar(max) = ''

SELECT 
Customers.CustomerName,
CountOfOrders.CountOfOrders,
@resultstring as Result

From 
--Get some basic data from the query's base table:
(Select 'James Bond' as CustomerName) Customers


--Get some extra data about James Bond's orders from a different table,
--Let's just say he's got 35 orders:
OUTER APPLY (
                SELECT CAST(35 AS INT) as CountOfOrders
            ) CountOfOrders


--Now do some number crunching:
Set @CountOfOrders = CountOfOrders.CountOfOrders
IF @CountOfOrders > 10 set @resultstring = @resultstring + 'James Bond has greater than 10 orders. '
IF @CountOfOrders > 20 set @resultstring = @resultstring + 'James Bond has greater than 20 orders. '
IF @CountOfOrders > 30 set @resultstring = @resultstring + 'James Bond has greater than 30 orders. '
IF @CountOfOrders > 40 set @resultstring = @resultstring + 'James Bond has greater than 40 orders. '
IF @CountOfOrders > 50 set @resultstring = @resultstring + 'James Bond has greater than 50 orders. '
```

Answer (score 1):

How about using `concat_ws()` on top of a series of `case` expressions?

```
concat_ws(
    ' ',
    case when CountOfOrders > 10 
        then concat(CustomerName, ' has more than 10 orders.')
    end,
    case when CountOfOrders > 20 
        then concat(CustomerName, ' has more than 20 orders.')
    end,
    case when CountOfOrders > 30 
        then concat(CustomerName, ' has more than 30 orders.')
    end
) as result
```

You add more epwresssions to `concat_ws()` as needed. This functions should be placed directly in your `select`  clause (and then you don’t need the variable).

Answer (score 1):

You can just use `CONCAT_WS()` (or a similar construct in older versions of SQL Server:

```
select @resultstring = CONCAT_WS(' ',
                                 (CASE WHEN CountOfOrders > 10 THEN 'James Bond has greater than 10 orders.' END),
                                 (CASE WHEN CountOfOrders > 20 THEN 'James Bond has greater than 20 orders.' END),
                                 . . .
                                )
from . . .;
```

Answer (score 1):

Re arrange the code

```
DECLARE 
@CountOfOrders int = 0,
@resultstring varchar(max) = ''

--Get some extra data about James Bond's orders from a different table,
--Let's just say he's got 35 orders:

--Now do some number crunching:
Set @CountOfOrders = (
                SELECT CAST(35 AS INT) as CountOfOrders
            ) 
IF @CountOfOrders > 10 set @resultstring = @resultstring + 'James Bond has greater than 10 orders. '
IF @CountOfOrders > 20 set @resultstring = @resultstring + 'James Bond has greater than 20 orders. '
IF @CountOfOrders > 30 set @resultstring = @resultstring + 'James Bond has greater than 30 orders. '
IF @CountOfOrders > 40 set @resultstring = @resultstring + 'James Bond has greater than 40 orders. '
IF @CountOfOrders > 50 set @resultstring = @resultstring + 'James Bond has greater than 50 orders. ' 

SELECT 
Customers.CustomerName,
@CountOfOrders,
@resultstring as Result

From 
--Get some basic data from the query's base table:
(Select 'James Bond' as CustomerName) Customers
```